# Im trying to show ad before listener prints ad loaded

Tags: flutter, admob

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    loadInter();
  }

  loadInter() {
    final adState = Provider.of<AdState>(context);
    adState.initialization.then((status) {
      interAd = InterstitialAd(
          adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUnitId,
          request: AdRequest(),
          listener: adState.listener);
      interAd.load();
    });
  }
```

im a bit unsure where to put `interAd.show();` i want to call it when the listener has printed `I/flutter (10349): Ad loaded.` but i keep calling it to early and get `E/FlutterInterstitialAd(10349): The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.`

The adstate class

```
class AdState {
  Future<InitializationStatus> initialization;

  AdState(this.initialization);

  String get bannerAdUnitId => Platform.isAndroid
      ? "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
      : "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";

  final AdListener listener = AdListener(
    // Called when an ad is successfully received.
    onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
      
      print('Ad loaded.');
    },
    // Called when an ad request failed.
    onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
      print('Ad failed to load: $error');
    },
    // Called when an ad opens an overlay that covers the screen.
    onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('Ad opened.'),
    // Called when an ad removes an overlay that covers the screen.
    onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => print('Ad closed.'),
    // Called when an ad is in the process of leaving the application.
    onApplicationExit: (Ad ad) => print('Left application.'),
  );
}
```

I would like to do the `show();` when the listeners `onAdLoaded(Ad ad)` is called. I tried to implement a AdListener to the state class but that doesnt call that function in my state class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not `await`ing for the initialization to finish properly. Try tagging your `loadInter` method as `asnyc` and `await` for the initialization to finish. Then you can load the ad, and then you can add a setter to your `AdState` class, passing the loaded ad to show it when the listener notifies you that the ad was loaded.

```dart
class AdState {
  Future<InitializationStatus> initialization;

  // This field will let you store the ad.
  InterstitialAd _ad;

  AdState(this.initialization);

  void setAd(InterstitialAd ad) {
    _ad = ad;
  }

  String get bannerAdUnitId => Platform.isAndroid
      ? "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
      : "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";

  final AdListener listener = AdListener(
    // Called when an ad is successfully received.
    onAdLoaded: (_) {
      if (_ad != null) {
        _ad.show();
      }
    },
    // Called when an ad request failed.
    onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
      print('Ad failed to load: $error');
    },
    // Called when an ad opens an overlay that covers the screen.
    onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('Ad opened.'),
    // Called when an ad removes an overlay that covers the screen.
    onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => print('Ad closed.'),
    // Called when an ad is in the process of leaving the application.
    onApplicationExit: (Ad ad) => print('Left application.'),
  );
}
```

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    loadInter();
  }

  void loadInter() async {
    final adState = Provider.of<AdState>(context);
    adState.setAd(interAd);
    final status = await adState.initialization;
    interAd = InterstitialAd(
          adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUnitId,
          request: AdRequest(),
          listener: adState.listener);
    await interAd.load();
  }
```

It may be cleaner to update the ad and to show it when the listener of the `InterstitialAd` provides you with a `.loaded` event. See [this medium article on how to add AdMob in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/adding-admob-to-your-flutter-app-part-2-2d84648402b4) for the details and a code sample.

Comment: Where do i now put `interAd.show();`? Ive tried with `interAd.load().then((value){interAd.show();});` but still calls it to early

Comment: You need to wait for the ad to load. So, again, you could apply the same strategy and `await` for the ad to load before calling the `show` method. It looks like you are not properly `await`ing when you use the `then` for some reason. See my edited answer for more info.

Comment: I updated my post a bit, is not the listener the same as an adevent like they implemented in that code. Since he added the event to the listener.

Comment: The interAd.show() works if i add a button to display it. i just want to show it on startup of the widget, thats where im having issues

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your problem a bit better now. I've updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: ive tried something similar but get the error. `The instance member '_ad' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressiondart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)
`. Not allowed to access the variable in there.

Comment: Instead of assigning the listener inmediately like `final AdListener listener = AdListener(...);`, try doing the same thing we've done with the `InterstitialAd` and add a setter to the `AdState` to set the listener.